# Purpose of Definition Phase and specifically the Example Questions

Tags: discussion, area-51, definition-phase

It seems that quite a few people don't quite understand the full purpose of the definition phase and the example questions.  The [FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) states

> The goal is to come up with at least 40 questions that embody the topic's scope.

which to easily can be taken that the whole goal is to achieve 40 questions with a score of 10.  With that any vote that brings the score above 10 is a "wasted" vote.

From reading between the lines, looking around the StackExchange sites, poking around proposals in various stages, and a lot of pondering I think I kind of have an idea.  But still I'd have a hard time to convey how these questions define the new site and add value to the proposal process.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Area 51, which has its own meta site: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

The point of the Definition phase is to work out which questions would be on-topic (and which off-topic) before getting started with answering. It's important to figure this out so that from the beginning you can be careful about what questions are allowed and which are not.

Going through this phase has several key benefits, including:

- It's a good first step to see whether there are enough good quality questions to ask about the topic.
- Sites with a lot of questions that are likely to result in extended debate can be weeded out before the arguments start.
- You can get a better feel for what the site is about than you can with a description, no matter how clearly worded.
- You can hit the ground running - when the site goes into beta there's plenty of questions to answer rather than an empty list.
- You can have a proper look at the questions on their own before anyone starts answering.